# Phonegap Plugin for Json parsing

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to `phonegap`, I'm trying to develop a app by using API references. While posting the data to the API URL I'm getting the result data in `HTML` format, but when I tried it in a browser the result I'm getting is in `JSON` format.

What should I do, or is there any plugin available to handle this?

The same API url works fine in Native Android App.

Comment: can you provide us some code?

Comment: $.post('https://www.residentsinc.com/servlet/LoginService',{"user_id":$("#username").val(),"pwd":$("#password").val()},function(data){
              alert(data);
              var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
              if(obj.success==true){
              //alert(obj.success);
              //$("#content").html(data);
              window.location.href="profilemenu.html";
              }else{
               navigator.notification.alert("Username/password is invalid");
              }
             });

Comment: please put the code in your post to make it more readable. You can edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is fixed.

The API provider provides the API in the `GET` method.

But in the document it was given as `POST`.